# Adding two values and auto fill the form in script

Tags: javascript, jquery, autofill

I have given two values(numbers) in a form, it has to get added and auto fill in the next field in form. I have tried many ways but it didn't work.
Is there any other option to do??

Comment: its unclear...please post your code already what you are done

Comment: what you tried???? post your code

Comment: Your question is very unclear at the moment. Could you please provide existing code which you have already tried and pin point to what didn't work. If you could provide a jsfiddle to see an example it would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want a total of two value in third text box like calculator. you need to use JavaScript and calculate two number and  set answer in third text box.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function sum()       {  
    var start = document.getElementById('edit-submitted-start-mileage').value;        
    var end = document.getElementById('edit-submitted-end-mileage').value;   
    var result = parseInt(start) + parseInt(end);    
     if (!isNaN(result)) {   
       document.getElementById('edit-submitted-total-miles').value = result;  
         }  
    }
```

I have used this code for adding the two values and autofilling the sum in the third textbox, but this didnot work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function add()
 {
    var n1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n1').value);

    var n2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n2').value);
    n3 = n1+n2;
    document.getElementById('n3').value = n3 ;
 }
```

```
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="n1"/>
        <input type="text" id="n2"/>
        <input type="button" value="add" onclick="add()"/>
        <br/>
       <input type="text" id="n3"/>
     </form>
```